# Treating a Multi Task Problem as Single Task

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, multiclass-classification, multilabel-classification, multitask-learning

In my model, the input is textual data. I have 5 targets, and each can take values from 0 to 5 (categorical values), which means that I am dealing with a multi-task problem and I need 5 heads for 5 multi-class classifications. When I used this approach, the result was bad ( I should mention that I used loss = loss1+loss2+...+loss5 for the loss function). Then I onehotencode my targets and using the same approach my result got a little better.

Then I tried something else. This time, I saw the problem as a multi-label problem (30 labels). so my model's logit output's shape would be like [Nbatches, 30]. Then I separated every 6 values (i.e logit1= output[:,0:6],..., logit5= output[:,24:30] because despite normal multi-label problems that all the out values can be 1, in my model only one of each 6 separated values can be 1. So, I took argmax of each logit and used multi-class classification metrics to evaluate my model and the result was amazing and also consistent among using different training sets. My question is whether this approach is valid since I am treating an original multi-class classification as a multi-label problem.